# How to remove gap between two textview in android

Tags: android, listview

How to remove gap between two listview ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFpFg.jpg

How i remove gap between welcome Sajid Ali  and ***_*____** line?

Below is my  code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnabletoProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="aaaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"

        android:text="Welcome Sajid Ali"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00" />


    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
        android:text="___________________ "


        android:textColor="#99CC00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblYouraccountbalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFCC00" />
```

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="0dip" for  <TextView
        android:paddingTop="0dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
        android:text="___________________ "


        android:textColor="#99CC00" />

Answer (score 2):

Reduce or Remove 
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dip" 
on all textviews other than the 1st one.

Comment: no is necessary u see pic i want to show text view on right side of screen

Comment: To make it on right side, add layout_gravity = "right" for the textview, if u add margin between textviews, it will be a gap. u have to remove it.

Comment: Did u try reducing the height, or setting it to wrapcontent for the 3rd textview?

Comment: Also set gravity="top" for the 3rd textview

Answer (score 2):

1) remove `android:layout_weight="..."`

2) use this code in your layout:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="-3dip"
android:layout_marginRight="-3dip"
android:layout_marginTop="-3dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="-3dip"
```

Comment: no this is wrong i don ot show on left side i want show textview o n right side oc screen

Answer (score 1):

Remove `18dp` in the `android:layout_height="18dp"`  parameter and change it to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 0):

Decreases the layout *heigth for remove gap between welcome Sajid Ali and*  line

```
   android:layout_height="10dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You first change layout height to `wrap_content` and for line use View instead of Text View.

```
<View
   android:id="@+id/view1"
   android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="2dip"
   android:background="#FFCC00" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try dis in between your text View   it will work  in your xml

```
    <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="1dip" android:background="#EFEFEF" />
```

Comment: @HayyaAnam You ca n Use a different LinearLayout i will Edit My Answer

Answer (score 0):

just add `android:marginTop` to your `"___________" TextView` and assign a negative value. e.g. `-10dp`.

But well, adding a `View` with `background` and height `1dp` or `2dp` would look more elegant. Consider using that, instead of `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
use View for line
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblUnabletoProceed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:text="aaaa" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblWelcome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"

        android:text="Welcome Sajid Ali"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/Hline1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#99CC00" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblYouraccountbalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFCC00" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="#EFEFEF"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="#EFEFEF"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5px" android:paddingRight="5px" >
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#EFEFEF" android:paddingLeft="2px" android:paddingRight="2px">

        <TableRow>
        <TextView style="@style/newFormCss.hdrLabel" />
        <TextView android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="Welcome Sajid Ali :"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#e68c10" android:gravity="top"/>

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="---------------------------"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#e68c10" android:gravity="top"/>

        </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:text="Valance: 66+5+6"  android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#e68c10" android:gravity="top"/>

        </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy solution :
set gravity as bottom for welcome text and set gravity as top for *_*_ text